# Passing from a Controller to a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Pretty new to RoR. Wonder if anyone can help me with this issue.

I got a gem called "business_time" which calculates the business days between two dates. I have set up a method in the model which does all the calculations.

I have a field called "credit" which should hold the number of business days. Here's what I have:

MODEL

```
def self.calculate(from_date,to_date)
   days = 0

   date_1 = Date.parse(from_date)
   date 2 = Date.parse(to_date)
   days = date_1.business_days_until(date2)

   days
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
def new
   @vacation = current_user.vacations.build
   @vacations = Vacation.calculate(:from_date, :to_date)
end
```

I got an error referencing something about a string.

Furthermore, how do I go about storing the data from the method into the field called "credit"?

Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the exact error? Please post it in the question. Also as i can see you are using `calculate_days` instead of `calculate` which is your model method.

Comment: `Date.parase`? Do you mean `Date.parse`?

Comment: @spickermann and Pavan, whoops. Typed it wrongly here. Nonetheless, is that the right way of passing from a controller to a model right? How do I go about storing the data in the "credit" field?

Comment: The `:from_date`, `:to_date` should be *Date objects* rather than *attributes*, so that `calculate` method receives the correct arguments.

Comment: @Pavan both :from_date and :to_date are DateTime objects when I initially setup the field.

Comment: What model has a `credit` attribute? The model with the `self.calculate` method?

Comment: @spickermann yep. same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need for an extra method, since all attributes (`from_date`, `end_date` and `credit`) are stored in the same model.

I would just set `from_date` and `end_date` in the initializer and calculate `credit` with a callback before validation:

```
# in the model
before_validation :calculate_credit

private
  def calculate_credit
    if from_date && to_date
      # `+ 1` because the user takes off both days (`from_date` and `to_date`),
      # but `business_days_until` doesn't count the `from_day`. 
      self.credit = from_date.business_days_until(to_date) + 1
    end
  end

# in the controller
def new
  @vacation = current_user.vacations.build
end

def create
  @vacation = current_user.vacations.build(vacation_params)

  if @vacation.save
    # @vacation.credit would return the calculated credit at this point
  else
    # ...
  end
end

private
  def vacation_params
    params.require(:vacation).permit(:from_date, :to_date)
  end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had to add `+1` at the end of the `self.credit`. Other than that, awesome!

Comment: @Jose: You are right, this happens because `business_days_until` doesn't include the `from_day`, but only counts the numbers of business days until the `to_day` is reached. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! You are a champ. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is pass `String` objects instead of `Symbol` objects.

So instead of `@vacations = Vacation.calculate(:from_date, :to_date)`, you probably need to pass `params[:from_date]` and `params[:to_date]` which should be strings like `20/01/2016`, etc...

Your code should be

```
@vacations = Vacation.calculate(params[:from_date], params[:to_date])
```

Comment: That seems correct to me, if you are indeed passing parameters to the `#new` action.  If not, you could set default arguments (such as `Date.today` and `Date.today + 1`) in the function, if that makes sense for your context.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I am getting the following error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: So your `params[:from_date]` or `params[:to_date]` is nil, that is an error from `Date#parse`